# Ajax and ASP.NET MVC- Get page URL, not the controller/action URL

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Ajax method that calls an MVC action from a controller class.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/ajax/Updates/Message",

    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        //data variable has been declared already
        data = response;
    },
    complete: function () {

        if (data !== "") {
            $('#div1').text(window.location.path);
            $('#div2').text(data);
        }
    },

});



[HttpGet]
public async Task < ActionResult > Message()
{
    string d = "test string";
    return Json(d, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The 'url' within the Ajax method is the call to the action method.

What to do if I want to return the actual page URL in Ajax Response, not the controller/action url?

So this controller does not have a view or anything associated with it, it is more like a helper class. When I am using ajax in any of the other pages, it is not returning the URL path of that specific page (via 'window.location.path) e.g. /Accounts/Summary , rather it is returning Updates/Message (in reference to the controller and action)

Answer (score 0):

The web is stateless, when you call Updates/Message with ajax, it doesn't know it's for page Accounts/Summary. You'll have to pass this as parameter (post or get) or you could try Request.UrlReferrer which should contain the url of the page that called the request.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you try this code:

ajax code

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.action("Message","Updates")', // url.action(ActionName,ControllerName)
            success: function (data) {
            window.location = data; 
            },
            error: function (xhr) { // if error occured
                alert("Error occured.please try again");
            }
            dataType: 'json'
        });
```

actionresult :

```
  [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Message()
        {
            string d = "http://www.google.com";
            return Json(d, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```